# version solving failed in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

today I was trying to integrate firebase but when I did pub get it throws me version error like-:

```
C:\Src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in fire...                      

Because firebase_auth 0.18.4+1 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.3 and no versions of firebase_auth match >0.18.4+1 <0.19.0, firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 requires firebase_core ^0.5.3.
So, because fire depends on both firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 and firebase_core ^0.6.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fire depends on both firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 and firebase_core ^0.6.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

following are the dependencies that I am using right now...

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


#  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  intl:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.15.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_core: ^0.6.0
```

does any know how to solve this kind of error as I tried to change the version number but then I show an error in core or auth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


#  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  intl:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.15.0
  firebase_auth: any
  firebase_core: any
```

Answer (score 0):

dependencies:
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.5
firebase_auth: any
flutter:
sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

Or you can use this version
dependencies:
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+3
flutter:
sdk: flutter

you can use this. Any will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).